# How to configure docker container proxy?

Tags: docker, proxy

I am newbie for docker. I try set a proxy for debian:jessie image but i didnt make it. I follow this [link](https://codepoets.co.uk/2014/debian-http_proxy-setting/) . I apply all of them with cat tag (example: 'cat > proxy.sh' , because vi or another editor not installed ) but there is some error about my proxy in apt-get update command.

**Error Photo**

[image]

My proxy : http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set the proxy environment variables when *starting* the container, for example:

```
docker container run \
  -e HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com \
  -e HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com \
  myimage
```

If you want the proxy-server to be automatically used when starting a container, you can configure default proxy-servers in the Docker CLI configuration file (`~/.docker/config.json`). You can find instructions for this in the [networking section](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) in the user guide.

For example:

```
{
  "proxies": {
    "default": {
      "httpProxy": "http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com",
      "httpsProxy": "http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com"
    }
  }
}
```

To verify if the `~/.docker/config.json` configuration is working, start a container and print its `env`:

```
docker container run --rm busybox env

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=220e4df13604
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
HOME=/root
```

Comment: Where's the proxy domain registered? Is the DNS that it's registered in accessible by docker? What happens if you specify the proxy's IP-address instead of the domain name? `Could not resolve` indicates a DNS issue.

Comment: This was helpful. I had assumed that setting the proxy in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf` would do this, but apparently that is only for docker daemon (like `docker pull` commands, not for containers).

Comment: If I set up the `~/.docker/config.json` and I run a container and then `printenv`, I don't see the env var `httpProxy` and it doesn't work.

Comment: The environment variables are named different than the options in `config.json`; `httpProxy` sets the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable

Comment: This didn't work for me either... I used a simple html boilerplate site which accesses for example the jquery cdn and google analytics but there is nothing showing in my proxy logs. If I build the nginx image, it does go through the proxy to pull the packages it needs. So it seems like the httpProxy settings are not passed to the containers...

Comment: I added a step to check if the configuration is applied

Comment: Thought setting in the Docker's GUI (Win 10) was enough

Comment: I print the env as mentioned above but it's not printing the proxy details in the config.json. Am I missing anything can someone please help me

Comment: Stupid mistake: I created the `.docker` folder in the wrong folder. Don't forget the `~/`

Comment: Watchout, some distributions require you to use lower case so consider using '-e http_proxy ...' instead of '-e HTTP_PROXY ...'

Comment: The `~/.docker/config.json` option will set both; it sets both `http_proxy` and `HTTP_PROXY` if you configured it.

Answer (score 5):

you need instruct the apt script to connect through proxy inside the container

```
# echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "proxy:port/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/40proxy
```

remember, this should be written inside the container

and in the machine that have docker running, the proxy should be configured like people said before in their comments

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the proxy server in quotes for it to work for me.

```
docker container run \
  -e HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com" \
  -e HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com" \
  myimage
```