# how to configure docker containers proxy?

Tags: docker, go, go-agent, goa

how to configure docker containers proxy ?

First of all,

I tried to use the way that setted '/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf' (https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) and it really works for docker daemon, but it doesn't work for docker containers, it seems this way just take effect for some command like 'docker pull'

Secondary,

I have a lot of docker containers, I don't want to use 'docker run -e http_proxy=xxx... ' command every time when I start a container.

So I guess if there is such a way automatically load the global configuration file when the container starts, I googled it and got it to set the file '~/.docker/config.json'([How to configure docker container proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827496/how-to-configure-docker-container-proxy).Unfortunately), this way still does not work for me.

(
  my host machine system is centos7, here is my docker -v:
     Docker version 1.13.1, build 6e3bb8e/1.13.1
)

I feel that it may be related to my docker version or the docker started by the systemd service, so ~/.docker/config.json does not take effect.

Finally ,

I just hope that modifying configuration files will allow all my containers to automatically configure environment variables when it start (that is auto set environment variables 'http_proxy=http://HostIP:8118 https_proxy=http://HostIP:8118' when a container start, like Dockerfile param ENV) . I want to know if there is such a way? And if this way can be realised I can make the container use the host's proxy, after all, my host's agent is working properly.

But I was wrong, I tried to run a container,then set http_proxy=http://HostIP:8118 and https_proxy=http://HostIP:8118, but when I use the command 'wget facebook.com' and I got 'Connecting to HostIP:8118... failed: No route to host.', But, the host machine(centos7) can successfully execute the wget, And I can successfully ping the host in the container. I don't know why it might be related to firewalls and the 8118 port.

It is Over,

OMG.. I have no other way, can anyone help me?

==============================

ps:
You can see from the screenshot below, I actually want to install goa and goagen but report an error, maybe because of network reasons, I want to open the agent to try, so...only have the above problem.

1.my go docker container
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzBvY.png)

[go docker wget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7C6B.png)

2.my host

[my host wget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmUE9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version 17.07 or more recent to automatically pass the proxy to containers you start using the config.json file. The 1.13 releases are long out of support.

This is well documented from docker:
https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/