# Passing local proxy to docker container under Mac

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, localhost

Following up on
[How to configure docker container proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827496/how-to-configure-docker-container-proxy)

I'm having problem passing my localhost proxy into docker container:

```
$ curl --proxy socks5://localhost:18888 https://goolge.ca
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>

docker run -ti -p 18888:18888 ...

# within docker
$ curl --proxy socks5://localhost:18888 https://goolge.ca
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 18888: Connection refused

$ curl --proxy https://localhost:18888 https://goolge.ca
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 18888: Connection refused

$ curl --proxy http://localhost:18888 https://goolge.ca
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 18888: Connection refused

$ curl --proxy socks5://0.0.0.0:18888 https://goolge.ca
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 18888: Connection refused
```

- This is under macOS.
- I also tried to pass `--net=host` from docker cli, but the result is the same.

What I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the commands in docker container's bash then you should use

```sh
#within docker
$ curl --proxy socks5://0.0.0.0:18888 https://goolge.ca
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. See my updated question.